# cross-compile a library with poky

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a library includes a `CMakeLists.txt` file. 
For a single hello.c file, I am using that command:

`arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/poky/1.7.2/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi hello.c -o helloworld`

How can I compile a library includes more than one source file and cmake?

Comment: Have you written anything in you ` CMakeLists.txt`? What have you tried?

Comment: @Anders there is already a CmakeLists.txt file, I am trying to compile leptonica

Comment: Well, if you want help with a  `CMakeLists.txt`, it helps if you show it to us... Together with what you've tried sofar.